# Batch command to unzip a file without any additional tool

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can any one help me out to find a batch command to unzip a file.
I do not want to use any external tool just want to unzip using .bat file.

Comment: check this -> http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911053/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-vbscript-using-internal-windows-xp-options-in

Answer (score 2):

Ths is not possible. the windows command line does not provide support for this.